# Minification of JS file using RequireJS Optimizer

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am working on minification of 3(one.js,two.js,three.js) JS files using require.js. The 3 js files have 3 alert messages. These 3 js files is being called using main.js file.

**One.js:**

```
define([], function one() {
    alert("one");
});
```

**Two.js:**

```
define([], function two() {
    alert("two");
});
```

**Three.js:**

```
define([], function three() {
    alert("three");
});
```

**Main.js:**

```
require(["./scripts/one", "./scripts/two", "./scripts/three"], function (one, two, three) {
});
```

**Main_built.js:**

```
define("app/scripts/one",[],function(){alert("one")}),define("app/scripts/two",[],function(){alert("two")}),define("app/scripts/three",[],function(){alert("three")}),require([],function(e,t,n){}),define("app/main",function(){});
```

Later I created Main_built.js and trying to use it and expecting that no http calls should be made to one,two and three js files, but still I am seeing calls to them in the Fiddler tool.

On running my application, although the Main_built.js is loaded with minified contents of all other js file.

The thing that I am expecting is on executing the application, it should only load the Main_built.js, and should not call any other js files. But i can see it is calling one.js, two.js etc along with Main_built.js

Below is the link I have taken reference from-

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Comment: How are you referencing the scripts from your main HTML page?

Comment: hi Deif, <script data-main="build/Main_built" src="app/scripts/require.js"></script> and <script src="build/Main_built.js" ></script>  These are the two way I have tried referencing the javascript file in my main html page. Both of them does not work.